# Regex to match Table of contents pattern

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Considering

```
NN = number/digit
x = any single letter
```

I want to match these patterns:

```
1. NN
2. NNx
3. NN.NN
4. NN.NNx
5. NN.NN.NN
6. NN.NN.NNx
```

Example that needs to be match:

```
1. 20
2. 20a
3. 20.20
4. 20.20a
5. 20.20.20
6. 20.20.20a
```

Right now I am trying to use this regex:

```
\b\d+\.?\d+\.?\d+?[a-z]?\b
```

But if fails.

Any help would be greatly appreciate, thanks! XD

EDIT:

I am matching this:

```
<fn:footnote fr="10.23.20a">    (Just a sample)
```

Now I have a regex that will extract the '10.23.20a'

Now I will check if this value will be valid, the 6 examples above will be the only string that will be accepted.

This examples are invalid:

```
1. 20.a
2. 20a.20.20
3. etc.
```

Many thanks for your help men! :D

Comment: Is `1.` to `6.` (and the following space) part of your input?

Comment: No it's just the enumeration of the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always have `\d+`, which is one or more digits. So you require at least three digits. Try grouping the digits with their periods:

```
^\d+(?:[.]\d+){0,2}[a-z]?$
```

The `?:` is just an optimization (and a good practice) that suppresses [capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). `[.]` and `\.` are completely interchangeable, but I prefer the readability of the former. Choose whatever you like best.

If you actually want to capture the numbers and the letter, there two options:

```
^(?<first>\d+)(?:[.](?<second>\d+))?(?:[.](?<third>\d+))?(?<letter>[a-z])?$
```

Note that the important point is to group a period and the digits together and make them optional together. You could as well use unnamed groups, it doesn't really matter. However, if you use my version, you can now access the parts through (for instance)

```
match.Groups["first"].Value
```

where `match` is a `Match` object returned by `Regex.Match` or `Regex.Matches` for example.

Alternatively, you can use .NET's feature of capturing multiple values with one group:

```
^(?<d>\d+)(?:[.](?<d>\d+){0,2}(?<letter>[a-z])?$
```

Now `match.Groups["d"].Captures` will contain a list of all captured numbers (1 to 3). And `match.Groups["letter"].Value` will still contain the letter if it was there.

Comment: @OskarKjellin I figured those `1.` to `6.` were just the enumeration of the examples

Comment: Thanks for this! But how about if I want to group them? I mean I want to get the 1st digit 2nd and 3rd and the letter respectively?

Comment: @JRC will it never be more than 3 parts?

Comment: yeap, its just 1-3 parts only, How can I group them so I can get them respectively? thanks for your help!

Comment: there's still 1 more problem that I see, if I try to input '22.d', it still matches '22', this should not be match.

Comment: @JRC why not? Do you mean there shouldn't be anything else in the string except for the pattern? Or would matching `22.23` in `"this 22.23 string"` be okay?

Comment: I think you've conflated your capture `(?<d>   )` and your pattern `\d+` in your last example, giving `(?<\d+>)`.

Comment: @JRC so which surrounding characters make the pattern invalid? letters, digits and periods? or will there always be double quotes to either side of the pattern?

Comment: any character (including space) to the left/right will make the pattern invalid. The double quotes will not be included in the extraction, in the example above only 10.23.20a will be extracted.

Comment: @JRC so you **do** want the pattern to be your entire string. then don't use `\b` (which means word boundary) but `^` and `$` instead (which means start and end of string, respectively). [See here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) and [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
^\d+(?:(?:\.\d+)*[a-z]?)$
```